# AngularJS - Filter on searchQueries (complex JSON)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I'm actually doing a filter for a WebApp I'm developing, the problem is I cannot manage to have a valid condition for the searchQuery.

I actually got that stuff:

```
myApp.filter('searchFilter', function() {
  return function(arrayToFilter, searchQuery, searchValue) {
    var baseArray = arrayToFilter;
    var usersSearchAfterQuery = [];
    var _searchQueryEmpty = {
      searchValue: searchValue,
      program: '',
      location: '',
      skillLevel: {
        shouldBeBeginner: false,
        shouldBeIntermediate: false,
        shouldBeExpert: false
      }
    };

    /**
     * true if the user has skillLevel at beginner
     * @param user
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    function isBeginner(user) {
      return (user.skillLevel.toLowerCase() === 'beginner');
    }

    /**
     * true if the user has skillLevel at intermediate
     * @param user
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    function isIntermediate(user) {
      return (user.skillLevel.toLowerCase() === 'intermediate');
    }

    /**
     * true if the user has skillLevel at expert
     * @param user
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    function isExpert(user) {
      return (user.skillLevel.toLowerCase() === 'expert');
    }

    /**
     * true if object1 and object2 has same program
     * @param object1
     * @param object2
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    function hasSameProgram(object1, object2) {
      return ((object1.program === object2.program));
    }

    /**
     * true if object1 and object2 has same location
     * @param object1
     * @param object2
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    function hasSameLocation(object1, object2) {
      return ((object1.location === object2.location));
    }

    /**
     * returns true if query1 === query2
     * @param query1
     * @param query2
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    function queriesAreEquals(query1, query2) {
      return (hasSameProgram(query1, query2)) &&     (hasSameLocation(query1, query2)) && (query1.skillLevel.shouldBeBeginner     === query2.skillLevel.shouldBeBeginner) &&     (query1.skillLevel.shouldBeIntermediate ===     query2.skillLevel.shouldBeIntermediate) &&     (query1.skillLevel.shouldBeExpert === query2.skillLevel.shouldBeExpert);
    }

    /**
     * if the filter is not empty or hasn't been reset
     */
    if (!queriesAreEquals(searchQuery, _searchQueryEmpty)) {
      console.log('Query is not empty');

      /**
       * second filter : if _user has the same values as in the filter
       */
      angular.forEach(arrayToFilter, function(_user) {

        if ((
              searchQuery.skillLevel.shouldBeBeginner && isBeginner(_user)) 
              || (searchQuery.skillLevel.shouldBeIntermediate && isIntermediate(_user)) 
              || (searchQuery.skillLevel.shouldBeExpert && isExpert(_user)
            ) 
            && (
                  hasSameLocation(_user, searchQuery) 
                  && hasSameProgram(_user, searchQuery)
                )
            ) {
              usersSearchAfterQuery.push(_user);
        }
      });
    }

    else if (searchValue !== null && typeof searchValue !== 'undefined' && searchValue.replace(/ /g, '') !== '') {
      if (typeof arrayToFilter !== 'undefined' && (searchValue.replace(/ /g, '') !== '' || searchValue.length !== 0)) {

        /**
         * first filter : if _user has the same skill as in searchValue
         */
        angular.forEach(arrayToFilter, function (_user) {
          if (_user.skill.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            usersSearchAfterQuery.push(_user);
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
      usersSearchAfterQuery = baseArray;
    }

    return usersSearchAfterQuery;
  };
});
```

So, I have to compare the searchQuery received as a parameter for the filter and then filter the arrayToFilter, after that the view should only display the users matching the query. The searchValue is the text entered in the search input.

My problem is : when I begin to filter the query, I got nothing displayed.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or just if I got a condition problem (I wish not, dat stupid condition wrecked me for 4 hours).

Do you guys have some magic potion for me ?

Thanks a lot !

Cheers.